# In Django python forms, how do I give a form field a 'second name'?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, model

I have a form on my website. The form is created using a python loop, which calls the fields by their variable name. Here is the HTML code:

```
{% csrf_token %}
  {% for form_field in task_form %}
    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
      <input class="input2" type="text" name="{{ form_field.name }}">
      <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="{{ form_field.name }}"></span>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

The variable {{ form_field.name }} is displayed on the website for each field, but it is a crude version of what I would like to actually display. This is how the fields are created in the python code:

```
class Task(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default = 'Untitled task ',blank=True,)
  description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
  cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True,default=0)
  profit = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True,default=0)
  start_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
  end_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
  hours_to_finish = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
  hours_finished = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
  project= models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  parent_task = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete= models.SET_NULL ,null=True,blank = True)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

is there any way I could call the form field with its name, but have a seperate variable tied to each field which I could call to display on the site, for example {{ form_field.nickname }}

Answer (score 0):

You could access `fields` dictionary in your form, so refer to your fields as:

```
<div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
  <input class="input2" type="text" name="{{ form.fields.project.name }}">
  <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="{{ form.fields.project.name }}"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the attribute `Field.label`.

If you are creating a `Form` from a model, the attribute `verbose_name` of the model field is used as label for the form field (as described in the [model form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#field-types)).

```
class Task(models.Model):
    ...
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True, verbose_name="Date started")
    ...


{% csrf_token %}
  {% for form_field in task_form %}
    <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
      <input class="input2" type="text" name="{{ form_field.name }}">
      <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="{{ form_field.verbose_name }}"></span>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

If you don't want to change your model, you can [override the defaults when creating the form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).

Note that there is also `help_text` which can be used to provide an explanation for a field.

Comment: The verbose_name solution didn't work, but I looked at the help text you provided and the 'labels' strategy worked. Thank you for linking that.

Answer (score 0):

I left models.py alone, but in forms.py, I added this to each form's Meta class:

```
fields = ('name', 'description', 'cost', 'profit', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'hours_to_finish', 'hours_finished', 'project', 'parent_task')
    labels = {
        'name': ('Task Name'),
        'description': ('Description'),
        'cost': ('Cost'),
        'profit': ('Profit'),
        'start_date': ('Start Date'),
        'end_date': ('End Date'),
        'hours_to_finish': ('Hours Remaining'),
        'hours_finished': ('Hours Completed'),
        'project': ('Parent Project'),
        'parent_task': ('Parent Task'),
    }
```

just make the field names apply to your form, and the names in the brackets will be displayed using {{ form_field.label }} instead of {{ form_field.name }}

I called it in the HTML like this:

```
{% csrf_token %}
        {% for form_field in task_form %}
        <div class="wrap-input2 validate-input" data-validate="Name is required">
          <input class="input2" type="text" name="{{ form_field.name }}">
          <span class="focus-input2" data-placeholder="{{ form_field.label }}"></span>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Make sure to include all fields you want renamed in the 'fields' array.